# What does return@ClassName mean in a Kotlin callback function?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to stop a callback from executing using the `return` keyword on the Button composable. Android Studio suggests that I write it like the `return@Button`. I want to know what this means or is there another way to stop the execution before it completes.

```
Button(
 onClick = {

        // ...
         return@Button
        // ...

    }){    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we are in a lambda, there are two types of returns. They have to use different syntax to distinguish them.

1. Local return. Return from the lambda function.
2. Non-local return. Return from the function that was declaring the lambda. Only allowed if the lambda is being passed to an inline function.

The `return@` syntax is called a "qualified return". Local returns must be qualified or implicit (the last expression in a lambda is implicitly returned). Bare `return`s are interpreted as non-local.

It's not `@ClassName`. It's `@NameOfFunctionLambdaIsParameterOf`. You are evidently using Compose, so `Button` is a function, not a class.

Alternatively, you can label your lambda whatever you like and use that label to return:

```
Button(
 onClick = onClick@{

        // ...
         return@onClick
        // ...

    }){    }
```

Read more about it [here in the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-to-labels).